# Unable to drilldown on Highcharts column graph due to the difficulty in converting the data in the required format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

With reference to the question posted on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108560/high-chart-async-drilldown), how can I return data of the below format from a controller using ajax? The confusing part is that if the data property is an array of objects - with a string and an integer property; then why doesn't the property names appear with the data? If it is an array of array then how is it possible to have an array of items of different types?

```
{
    'Animals': {
                name: 'Animals',
                data: [                  
                          ['Cows', 2],   
                          ['Sheep', 3]
                      ]
               },
    'Fruits':  {
                name: 'Fruits',
                data: [
                          ['Apples', 5],
                          ['Oranges', 7],
                          ['Bananas', 2]
                      ]
               },
    'Cars':    {
                name: 'Cars',
                data: [
                          ['Toyota', 1],
                          ['Volkswagen', 2],
                          ['Opel', 5]
                      ]
               }
}
```

I am using the following code to call the controller:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                        var chartObject = this;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethodName")',
                            type: "GET",
                            cache: false,
                            data: e.point.name,
                            datatype: "json",
                            success: function (dataList) {
                                debugger;

                                var chart = chartObject,
                                    drilldowns = dataList, //dataList must be in the required format.
                                    series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

                                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                            }
                        });

// The rest of the code below
//
//
```

Comment: Can you add a `jsfiddle` link for us to edit?

Comment: @paweł-fus could you please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you generate class using that format and then return the object of the class as serialized content from Action Results. So you need to do the followings

1) Create class from the JSon format. There is multiple online tool available for this like http://json2csharp.com/

2) After you populate the object of the class you can serialize the object using Javascript Serializer.

```
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Object);
```

3) Return the json string from action results.

```
return Content(json);
```